# How to map values from another column in python

Tags: python, pandas

Having 2 columns , I want to map values from **column3 to column1** if there is no value in column1, if column3 is also blank then no value will be mapped.

**Input Data**

```
column1    column2    column3

2225        India      2227
             UK        35604
32578       USA        38956
            Dubai
7528        Bhutan    
            India      37890
```

**Expected Output:**

```
column1    column2    column3

2225        India      2227
35604        UK        35604
32578       USA        38956
            Dubai
7528        Bhutan    
37890       India      37890
```

**Script i am trying to use :**

```
if df['column1'] = 'NaN':
   df['column1'] = df['column3']
```

**Please Suggest How i can map values from column3 to column1 if column1 is blank.**

Comment: `df['column1'] = df['column1'].fillna(df['column3'])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang - Thanks for the Answer, df['column1'] = df['column1'].fillna(df['column3']) maps the value from Column3 to column1 if column1 is blank, How i can map value from column3 to column1 if both the column values are different, What modification can e done in the above line.

Comment: `df['column1'] = df['column3']` ???

Comment: @QuangHoang  - I am looking to modify the line "df['column1'] = df['column1'].fillna(df['column3'])" with one more condition as if df['column1'] != df['column3'] , I need to update the value from column3 to column1, Please suggest.

Comment: I don't get your question, where `df['col1']` is `nan`, then it is **already** different from `df['col3']`. Where it is not `nan`, you also want to replace by the value in `column3`? Then that's just what I posted.

Comment: @QuangHoang ,  Exactly Sir, where df['col1'] is nan, Then we are updating from column 3 , I also want to replace column 1 with column 3 if both the values are different.

Comment: Did you try the other comment? What doesn't work?

Comment: @QuangHoang - Sir i have tried using the other comment as well , but doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: *doesn't seem to work* doesn't help. You need to specify *what* doesn't work, i.e. What you expect v.s. what you get. *Note*: `''` is **not** `nan`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232175/discussion-between-manz-and-quang-hoang).

Comment: @QuangHoang - Sir Shall i update the Question for the help i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `np.where`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': {0: 2225, 1: np.nan, 2: 32578, 3: np.nan, 4: 7528, 5: np.nan},
                   'column2': {0: 'India', 1: 'UK', 2: 'USA', 3: 'Dubai', 4: 'Bhutan', 5: 'India'},
                   'column3': {0: 2227.0, 1: 35604.0, 2: 38956.0, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: 37890.0}})

df['column1'] = np.where(df['column1'].isna(), df['column3'], df['column1'])
```

```
print(df)

   column1 column2  column3
0   2225.0   India   2227.0
1  35604.0      UK  35604.0
2  32578.0     USA  38956.0
3      NaN   Dubai      NaN
4   7528.0  Bhutan      NaN
5  37890.0   India  37890.0
```